# Get variable in conf.js and use it through spec files

Tags: protractor

This is what I have in protractor.conf.js:

```js
    let localNodeStorage = require('./helpers/localStorageNode');


    exports.config ={onPrepare: async () => {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));


   
    await browser.driver.get('https://xpert-integration.gdp3000.com/gdpadminui/login');
    localNodeStorage.clear();
    await browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#username')).sendKeys('user');
    await browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#password')).sendKeys('pass');
    await browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.btn-enter')).click();
    localNodeStorage.getValue("AuthenticationToken").then((token) => {
        let authToken= token;
        console.log(authToken);   
    });}};
```

Is there a way to access `authToken` in my login.ts class? And if so, how?

I tried `params{}` but it won't work
If I just get token from localStorage in login.ts I get authToken undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Hi if your params variable is **token** , then in onprepare call it as

```
browser.token , instead of browser.parans.token
```

Another way is to declare a global variable in config file and use it .

In JavaScript it's straight forward as putting

global  token , in the top of conf.js and using it as token anywhere else

You can also try out steps listed out in below stack overflow session:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/29406962/6793637

It include approachs like using environment variable ,getting full processedconfig and getting the params property from it , to name a few.